# chnage form action onchange() option filed and submit the same form not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jstl

I have a form where I have a dropdown selection box. My requirement is when the user changes the option from the select box then the form action should change accordingly and the form should be submitted automatically. I have the following code in my form section:

```
<form id="topicSelectionFormId" action="${headerLink.topicUrl}" method="GET">
    <select id="topic-option-id" class="dd-custome-new" onchange="changeTopic(this)">
        <c:forEach items="${headerLink.topicList}" var="topic">
            <option value="${topic.menuItemId}" ${topic.menuItemId == headerLink.topicId ? 'selected' : ''}>${topic.name}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
</form>
```

And then I have the javascript code to handle the form action change part as:

```
<script>
function changeTopic(sel){
    var topicId = sel.value;
    var formAction = $('#topicSelectionFormId').prop('action') + topicId;
    alert(formAction);
    $("#topicSelectionFormId").attr("action", formAction);
    $("#topicSelectionFormId").submit();
}
</script>
```

The alert is showing the correct required form action I need. But the form is not submitted to the desired url. Can anybody help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    function changeTopic(sel){
        var topicId = sel.value;
        document.topicSelectionFormId.action = topicId;
        document.topicSelectionFormId.submit();
    }
```

```html
    <form name="topicSelectionFormId" action="action-default" method="GET">
      <select id="sss" onchange="changeTopic(this);">
        <option value="action1">action1</option>
        <option value="action2">action2</option>
      </select>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is perfectly working in my IE11 browser. In browser's developer tools, check in network , whether your request is going to desired url and what response you are receiving.

This is not my answer, But I don't have enough reputations to comment under your question, so writing here

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to set to desired url in action..not formAction

Comment: $("#topicSelectionFormId").attr("action", formAction); here formAction is a variable name.